# Sharing source between 2 projects?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flash-builder, flex4.5

I have a project containing a big package "global" of classes which is designed for Web, I need to share these classes with a new mobile project, but when i add them with :

**Properties -> Flex Build Path -> Source path -> Add Folder**

they start appearing with index [source path] before the package name, and since them Flash Builder start trowing error messages :

*"A file found in a source-path must have the same package structure '', as the definition's package, 'global'."*

- How can i fix this issue ?

Comment: Is there a particular reason you're not compiling these 'global' classes into a library?

Comment: they sharing too much UI components inside. It is not much of clean design.

Comment: When you link to a library as 'merged', only the classes you use are actually compiled into the main application (and any classes they depend on).

Comment: this is good idea, but i must keep it this way if possible.

Comment: RIAstar - seems like creating a library is the best solution, please set it as an answer, so i can accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As we've discussed in the comments, I think it would be a better approach to compile your "global" classes into a **library** (.swc).
You were concerned about loading unnecessary classes: when you link to a library as '**merged**', only the classes you use are actually compiled into the main application (and any classes they depend on), so there's no need to worry about that.
As a last argument I also think this is a more **flexible** approach. A compiled library is easier to reuse and version, so the code can more easily be distributed to other developers on your team.

Comment: Thank You very much. I have successful separated the code into library, and shared it between Web, Window, Desktop and iOS application. Now There is 4 separate projects sharing one codebase :)

Answer (score 1):

Rename one of the packages with right click->refactor. Than is should work.

If not you can also try to have your two codes available at the same project, and then you can select which to run in Flash Builder, by right-clicking to that .as or .mxml file, and selecting set as ... (or something like that)

Comment: it is interesting idea, but refactoring a package name doesn't actually works, and appears that renaming it doesnt work aswell :|, and renaming/refactoring source files is not an option

Comment: you can try to put one global to a new folder (ex. globalImported) under the other project, and then set up a syncing method on your pc, to sync the globalImported with its original folder..

Answer (score 0):

I guess if you will include 'src' fonder instead of 'src/global' that problem will disappear.

Comment: nope, i tried with all available "direct" approaches which i think about. This was one of them, but it appearing that it doesnt work actually.